# Can I have two residence permits in two different EU countries?

Tags: eu, residency

I currently live in Italy with my wife who is an Italian and I have Italian residence permit card, can I apply for a Norweigian reisidence permit if my mother lives in Norway and is it possible to hold the two residence permits at the same time?

Comment: What's your  citizenship? So you're Norwegian or Sweden?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common sense suggests it's difficult to fully “reside“ in two countries at once. Either you care for your mother (the main way to qualify for a family member permit for extended family) and being there every other week isn't enough or you actually live with your wife. Splitting your time equally between both countries might just meet the standard for residence in each of them but it feels like you would be awfully close to lying about your intents when applying for a permit.

In any case, you can certainly apply for a new residence card elsewhere, there is no rule against that (that's also what you would be doing if you were to move permanently to Norway and never come back to Italy) and, to my knowledge, no system to exchange information between countries about those residence cards.

What *could* happen is that, come the time to renew your Italian residence card, it would be refused because you don't meet the definition of a resident anymore or are found to have effectively left the country. There are several reasons why it might still work in this case but that's what you should worry about. And vice versa for Norway.

Comment: There's no such thing as "*awfully close to lying about your intents*", because either it would have been valid and thus "fully recognized", or it would not have been valid and thus "fully unrecognized".

Comment: @Pacerier I honestly do not understand your point. What's "it" in your sentence? What do you mean by "valid"? And what does it have to do with whether the OP lied or not when applying for a permit?

Comment: Meaning the "*awfully close to lying about your intents*" doesn't matter as it wouldn't be relevant as far as the [legal fact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Question_of_fact) is concerned. The requirements are either met or they are not. If the requirement is to clock 100 days and you had that, then it's a pass. If the requirement is to clock 183 days and you had that, then it's a pass.

Comment: @Pacerier Of course, it matters, when it comes to immigration, it really works the other way around. The number of days is just the beginning and actually works against you: It means that, as a non-EU citizen, you need a residence permit (as opposed to a short-stay visa or visa-free stay). Intent, conditions of stay, etc. then become relevant, those are the actual requirements. They don't just hand out those by virtue of staying more than X days…

Comment: The intent is **only** accessed at the interview. And like every other interview people have prepared standard scripts to recite. In other words, before you enter the interview and after you exit the interview, your intent remains irrelevant. You could tell everyone you met on the street about your *real* intent and you'd still be a pass as that's irrelevant.

Comment: @Pacerier That's certainly not true in principle, it even sounds so absurd that I am beginning to wonder whether you have any experience at all with these matters or if are arguing in good faith. Note that I said nothing about the likelihood of being caught in the lie, the fact that the intent is only assessed at “the interview“ (which one?) is neither here nor there, it's a completely different question!

Comment: Also, what you do afterwards is directly relevant to what your intent originally was. Worse case scenario, it could be construed as evidence that you lied whenever you applied for the permit, which is even worse. Permits as family members of an EU citizen are a bit different because EU freedom of movement rights are very extensive but these kinds of things are not unusual for visas.

Comment: As said, it's the practice that matters and the so-called "in principle" is irrelevant.  [Visa interview tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+prepare+for+visa+interview) will teach you what to say and what you should not say. What is it that you say can be construed as evidence that you lied? The interview? Nah, my intent was just as I said it was, but intent changes with time sometimes as frequently as the weather. Separately, in U.S. people with non dual-intent visa (H-2B/ B-1/ F-1/ J-1/ etc) claim they dont intend to stay? And in the end tons of them become green card?

Comment: @Pacerier If you read the whole answer, you should see that I cover both the rules and their application. I do think it's important to understand the principles too. And neither the question nor my answer are about the US. In any case, many of the things you wrote are just plain wrong. It's fine to say the risk of facing adverse consequences is low in practice, not to claim that intent does not matter and then to make stuff up to cover up your mistake.

Comment: But what's your citizenship? Did you ever move to another country? It seems you have no idea how these things work in reality. For visas (a slightly different scenario but relevant nonetheless), entry refusals, revocations or even annulments because of discrepancies between what was said in the interview and what you do later do happen, it's not only a theoretical possibility. It might surprise you but just claiming “my intent was just as I said it was and I just changed my mind” won't always get you out of trouble.

Comment: As I mentioned, in U.S. people with non dual-intent visa claim they dont intend to stay and in the end they still manage to get green card from there. We can thus see that practice differs from principle, and as such **principle should not be treated as practice**. Btw, visa interview preparation is **common knowledge** and there's nothing to debate about that matter.  While my facts are pertaining to U.S. and not EU, they are very likely to share **similarities in approach** unless we have a **reference** stating otherwise.

Comment: @Parcerier Not only is it not particularly likely that they share a similar approach but it's simply not the case, *as I already explained*. But you just admitted that you don't know anything relevant… Is that really a sound basis to be so absolute and condescending?

Comment: ? The comments are just as they are, not meant to be interpreted as condescending. There's nothing to be condescending about on the Internet. As I said, this is the practice of U.S. and they are very likely to share similarities in approach unless we have a **reference** stating otherwise.