# Can I hold a residence permit for Italy and the UK at the same time?

Tags: united-kingdom, resident-permit, eu, schengen, italy

I hold a residence permit for Italy but will be moving to the UK to be with my partner. Can I keep both the permits?

Comment: How much time do you expect to spend in each country https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/taxes/income-taxes-abroad/index_en.htm? Will you still have a permanent address in Italy? Typically AFAIK a resident leaving Italy for good is required to notify the authorities and surrender their permit

Comment: @Traveller and maru Note that residence for tax purposes need not perfectly align with residence for immigration purposes. (+1 to the questions as that can be important)

Comment: Related question: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/6972/can-i-have-two-residence-permits-in-two-different-eu-countries