# Holding two EU temporary residence permit, is it possible?

Tags: schengen, eu, study

I'm a Tunisian citizen, resident in italy as a self-employed worker (2 years temporary residency permit), I recently got accepted to study in Portugal:

1. Do I need a visa ? or I can apply directly for study residency permit inside Portugal without requesting a specific visa?
2. Will moving to Portugal and holding its residency permit affect my status as a worker in Italy (knowing that I will renew the Italian residency permit in December this year) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I have 2 EU residency permits at once?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/can-i-have-2-eu-residency-permits-at-once)