# Residence permits in Italy and Ireland

Tags: student-visa, indian-citizens, italy, ireland, self-employment

Hello I'm holding self employment residence permit in italy and now i applied for student residence permit in
Ireland is it possible to maintain both of them or is it going to be a problem for me to travel to Italy.
Please let me know thank you

Comment: For completeness, what is your citizenship? Do you intend to maintain your self-employment status whilst a student?

Comment: Yes i want to maintain both I'm Indian citizen

Comment: Related question https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/20941/can-i-have-2-eu-residency-permits-at-once

Comment: Ireland is in the EU but it is part of the Common Travel Area  https://www.citizensinformation.ie/en/government_in_ireland/ireland_and_the_uk/common_travel_area_between_ireland_and_the_uk.html *not* the Schengen area. If you are not able to maintain your Italian residence while studying / residing in Ireland, you will need a visa to travel to Italy.

Comment: My intent is while going to or coming from Italy & Ireland if i show Self employment card to italy and Student card to come to Ireland any problems i face ?